# Does the hardware needs to be compatible for UNICODE to display various code points?

Tags: unicode, hardware, adapter

Does the hardware ( display adapter) needs to have an inbuilt knowledge of unicode character set to be able to display various characters of unicode? 
Will UNICODE work on the old computers of 80s or 90s? I am not sure about it. My understanding is that display adapter have some inbuilt memory of the character set it can display. 
Are the display adapters limited to a fixed a character set at the time of manufacturing?

Answer (score 3):

Video adapters on PC hardware have text and graphics modes. Text mode is limited to the OEM character set. No such limitation in graphics mode, it is just pixels turned on by the display driver. Even the BIOS these days goes into graphics mode right away.  So no, not limited by the hardware.

Comment: thanks.. assuming that we are in text mode only, now where is this OEM set stored? inbuilt the video hardware or the OS provides it?

Comment: In the video ROM.  It can be replaced, BIOS interrupt 0x10.  This stopped being relevant at least 15 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

No way, this was never the case for displays.